# jQuery Draggable not working on 1.9 version

Tags: jquery

i want to use `draggable()` function on jquery 1.9, after using that i cant move and drag window.
my example is on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjxfd/)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set the `z-index` in `stack`, as it will act as a selector and take it directly from the element (just be sure that the element has `z-index`)

```
$(".fenster").draggable({
    cancel: '.inhalt',
    containment: 'body',
    scroll: false,
    stack: '.fenster'
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjxfd/4/)